# "Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

When I open Android Studio it displays the following message:

```
"Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync"
```

and

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -Duser.country=RU -Duser.language=ru -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\chugu\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.6.4-all\ankdp27end7byghfw1q2sw75f\gradle-5.6.4\lib\gradle-launcher-5.6.4.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 5.6.4
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
-----------------------
Check the JVM arguments defined for the gradle process in:
- gradle.properties in project root directory
Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (5 s 637 m... (show 
balloon)
```

Please help me figure it out: `Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync` and `Gradle sync failed`.

[image: Screenshot of error message]